# Remove backslash string replace in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

How to replace the below string in C#?

**Current:** `"A,B,C"`

**Goal:** `"A","B","C"`

```
var text = St.Replace(",","\"");
```

**Current Result:** `"A\","B\","C\"`

How to remove backslash?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are quotation marks belong to a string ("A,B,C")? The result should be one string or 3 strings?

Comment: Now 3 string in 1 string. i want 3 string partly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this snippet,

```
string img = "A,B,C";
string res = img.Replace(",", "\",\"");
res = "\""+res + "\"";
```

Output:
"A","B","C"

Comment: Or the source string could have been: `string St = "\"A,B,C\""`, then your second line is moot.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are possibly going about this all wrong and if you just want to split that string into 3 then you should use the following code to get an array of 3 strings.

```
"A, B, C".Split(',')
```

or

```
string myString = "A,B,C";
myString.Split(',')
```